# Remove value from ehCache whose key starts with 'xyz'

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache

I have a requirement where I have to remove a key from particular cache which starts with some value eg `xyz`.

Actual key could be `xyz12345`, `xyzehrek`, `xyz5eei7`, etc.
I am using Spring annotation to remove a value from particular cache. I don't want to delete everything from from cache but only the objects with key which starts with `xyz`.

```
@CacheEvict(value="someCache", key="#keyStartsWith")
public void removeValueFromCache(String keyStartsWith) {

}
```

I tried to pass `"^#keyStartsWith"` in key. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have tried using condition attribute of @CacheEvict?

Comment: Can you provide more details about it?

Comment: Try this if it may help... http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CacheEvict.html#condition--

Comment: Tried lot. But it has limitations. No other option than implementing it in old fashion way like Abhishek has suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

I know a hackish way to do this.

First, in your code where you are storing the elements into the cache create a arraylist for storing keys exclusively.

```
ArrayList<String> keys
```

Now when you want to delete the the keys matching say "xyz", what you can do is

```
for (String key : keys)
    if (key.contains("xyz")
        cache.remove(key);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Abhishek. This solution was always in my mind but I will consider this as a last option if I will have no choice.